# Android - execute function if any button on soft keyboard is pressed

Tags: android, kotlin, keyboard, android-softkeyboard

I am trying to implement a function that will be executed when any key on softkeyboard is pressed. Any recommendations how to implment it?

Answer (score 0):

```
        /** Text Change **/
        input.doOnTextChanged { text, start, before, count ->
            // if text changed then keyboard event was triggered
        }

        /** Key Event >= 0 **/
        view.setOnKeyListener { view, code, keyEvent ->
            if (code >= 0) {
                // key event triggered
            }
            true
        }
```